# Start docker in background at boot

Tags: docker

I would like to autostart a docker container in the background at boot. I do not want it to start at login, but at boot (to serve a HTTP interface to all my colleagues on the LAN) before/without anyone logging in. I have tried to start the Docker App using a file in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, but it seems like the Docker App requires the user to be logged in first.

When googling, I get a lot of solutions for old VirtualBox style Docker, but I would prefer to use the official (xhyve) docker.

Running MacOS 10.12.1. Docker installed by just downloading the [Docker App dmg from Stable channel](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/).

Comment: Did you install xhyve and probably docker-machine-driver-xhyve with homebrew?

Comment: @klanomath, no I downloaded this dmg: https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg and drag-and-drop:ed Docker into my Applications.

Comment: Please add a link to one of the ***"lot of solutions for old VirtualBox style Docker"*** which fits your need.

Answer (score 1):

*    ***Under construction***

Docker for Mac is launched sandboxed (or not, if disabled in the Docker prefs) while logging in by a LogInItem in the application bundle probably using [this](https://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/) HelperApp method.

This is the reason why neither a launch agent nor a login item (in System Preferences > User & Groups > $USER > Login Item) is available.

---

Probably it's very costly to impossible to launch a user owned sandboxed container & webserver image to serve the wanted HTTP interface.

Maybe it's possible by using a classical method and installing xhyve & docker-machine-driver-xhyve with homebrew instead of a VirtualBox solution and linking the boot/user Docker environment and the user Docker environment.